# java.lang.RuntimeException: Found conflicting getters for name getOverlay on class android.widget.DatePicker

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Can someone help me with this error? I'm trying to get a birthday date from a DatePicker component, and save it in the Firebase Firestore, but I'm getting this error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Found conflicting getters for name getOverlay on class android.widget.DatePicker

the DatePicker component is the variable named dtNascimento and etDtNascimento

```
private fun createNewAccount() {
    nome = etNome!!.getText().toString()
    cpf = etCpf!!.getText().toString()
    dtNascimento = etDtNascimento


    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(nome) || TextUtils.isEmpty(cpf)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Entre com mais detalhes!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }else{

        val user = hashMapOf<String, Any?>(
                "nome" to nome,
                "cpf" to cpf,
                "dtNascimento" to dtNascimento
        )

        db.collection("pessoas")
                .add(user)
                .addOnSuccessListener {documentReference->
                    Log.d(tag, "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: ${documentReference.id}\"")
                }
                .addOnFailureListener{e->
                    Log.w(tag, "Error adding document", e)
                }

        Toast.makeText(this, "Informações preenchidas com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        updateUserInfoAndUI()
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry Frank, I was so engaged in coding that I forgot to give a feedback about your answer. Yes, it helped me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to write a date time **picker** view to the database with `dtNascimento = etDtNascimento`, which is not supported.

You probably want to write the actual date/time that was picked.

Also see:

- [How to get date and time from Date/Time Picker dialog and show it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45283857/how-to-get-date-and-time-from-date-time-picker-dialog-and-show-it)